# Python Click-through transparent window but excluding controls and contents

Tags: python, c++, winapi, pywin32, win32gui

So far my progress is this:

```
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Demo")
posX, posY, width, height = win32gui.GetWindowPlacement(hwnd)[4]

windowStyles = win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED | win32con.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE, windowStyles)
win32gui.SetWindowPos(hwnd, win32con.HWND_TOPMOST, posX,posY, 0,0, win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)

windowAlpha = 180
win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, win32api.RGB(0,0,0),
windowAlpha, win32con.LWA_ALPHA)
```

This code makes the "Demo" window click-through and transparent. But it includes all the controls and contents inside as well. I need only to make the window background (or everything with alpha 0) transparent and click-through, nothing else will be affected. Something like a desktop widget which will also be draggable. How can I achieve this?